# Подключение к Tarantool через Docker

Tags: java, docker, tarantool

Пытаюсь подключить tarantool через docker.
Написала вот такой compose файл

```
version: '2'

services:
  tarantool:
    container_name: mytarantool
    image: tarantool/tarantool:1.7
    environment:
      TARANTOOL_USER_NAME: "admin"
      TARANTOOL_USER_PASSWORD: "secret"
    ports:
      - 3301:3301
```

Запускаю докер, и всё вроде хорошо, контейнер создался

[демонстрация запуска compose файла](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPFUL.png)

[демонстрация созданного контейнера](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jh0g.png)

Но мне не удаётся подключиться к tarantool через плагин в idea

[демонстрация подключения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FGpr.png)
[ошибка подключения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTOXF.png)

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так? Лог\пас ввожу точно верный(пробовала уже compose и без пароля настраивать), не знаю может порт как-то не так указываю или ещё что...

Изначально пробовала настроить подключение через файл конфигурации и использовать репозиторий, но не выходит - репозиторий пустой.

Файл конфигурации вот

```
package com.example.demo.config;

import com.example.demo.repository.UserRepository;
import io.tarantool.driver.api.TarantoolClient;
import io.tarantool.driver.api.TarantoolClientConfig;
import io.tarantool.driver.api.TarantoolClusterAddressProvider;
import io.tarantool.driver.api.TarantoolServerAddress;
import io.tarantool.driver.auth.SimpleTarantoolCredentials;
import io.tarantool.driver.auth.TarantoolCredentials;
import io.tarantool.driver.core.ProxyTarantoolTupleClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.tarantool.config.AbstractTarantoolDataConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.tarantool.repository.config.EnableTarantoolRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableTarantoolRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
public class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractTarantoolDataConfiguration {

    @Value("${tarantool.host}")
    protected String host;
    @Value("${tarantool.port}")
    protected int port;
    @Value("${tarantool.username}")
    protected String username;
    @Value("${tarantool.password}")
    protected String password;

    @Override
    protected TarantoolServerAddress tarantoolServerAddress() {
        return new TarantoolServerAddress(host, port);
    }

    @Override
    public TarantoolCredentials tarantoolCredentials() {
        return new SimpleTarantoolCredentials(username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public TarantoolClient tarantoolClient(TarantoolClientConfig tarantoolClientConfig,
                                           TarantoolClusterAddressProvider tarantoolClusterAddressProvider) {
        return new ProxyTarantoolTupleClient(super.tarantoolClient(tarantoolClientConfig, tarantoolClusterAddressProvider));
    }
}
```

app файл вот

```
tarantool:
  host: jdbc:tarantool://localhost:3301
  port: 3301
  username: "admin"
  password: "secret"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в версии tarantool. Версии 1.x не поддерживают SQL.
С версией 2.2 всё ок.

Источник информации: https://github.com/tarantool-php/client/issues/56